# how to create batch insert in yii2

Tags: yii2, batch-insert

how to create batch insert

## view

two input number check and tow input price check and tow input date check

```
<input type='text' name="number_check[]">
<input type='text' name="price_check[]">
<input type='text' name="date_check[]">
<input type='text' name="number_check[]">
<input type='text' name="price_check[]">
<input type='text' name="date_check[]">
```

## controller

I don't know what to write ?????

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('sale_check',[
'number_check',
'price_check',
'date_check', 
'user_id', 
'sale_id', 
],$data)->execute() ;
```

Comment: update your question and add  the content of your $_POST  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to you sample where you have just two set of same fields you shoul populate the  $data array and perform execute()  of db command

```
  $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

  for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
    $data[$i][0] = $post[number_check][$i];
    $data[$i][1] = $post[price_check][$i];
    $data[$i][2] = $post[date_check][$i]; 
    $data[$i][3] = Your_value_for_user_id; 
    $data[$i][4] = Your_value_for_sale; 
  }

  Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('sale_check',[
    'number_check',
    'price_check',
    'date_check',
  ],
  $data
  )->execute();
```

Comment: Insert user_id and sale_id in batch insert